# Why do I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when I run my method on a grid of size of more than 5? I bolded the line where the error occurs

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, depth-first-search

The purpose of this method is to read a grid of 1's and 0's that I created previously, and apply depth first search to find a path of components. In the main method, I scan the grid for a starting component, or "seed," then call labelUsingDFS once a seed is found. 0's are background, 1's are components.

```
      public static boolean labelUsingDFS(Pixel [][] maze, int row, int col, int 
        componentNumber, ArrayStack stack){
        ArrayStack path = new ArrayStack(); 

        //initialize offsets
        Position [] offset = new Position[4];
        offset[0] = new Position(0,1);   //right
        offset[1] = new Position(1,0);   //down
        offset[2] = new Position(0,-1);  //left
        offset[3] = new Position(-1,0);  //up


        Position here = new Position(row, col);     
        maze[row][col].label = 0;   //prevent return 
        int option = 0;
        int lastOption = 3;

        //search for a path
        while(here.row != gridSize || here.col != gridSize) {
            int r = 0, c = 0; //row and column of neighbor
            while(option <= lastOption) {
                r = here.row + offset[option].row;
                c = here.col + offset[option].col;
                if(maze[r][c].label == 0) break;                
                option++;
            }
     //was a neighbor found??
            if(option <= lastOption){    //yes      
                path.push(here);
                **here = new Position(r, c);**
                maze[r][c].label = 0;                   //set to 0 to prevent revisit
                option = 0;
            } else { //no neighbor to move to, back up  
                if(path.empty()) {
                    return false;
                }

                Position next = (Position) path.pop();
                if(next.row == here.row) {
                    option = 2  +next.col - here.col;
                } else {
                    option = 3 + next.row - here.row;
                    here = next;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: probably a never ending loop - check the stack trace. The condition for the first loop is very *weak* - will only stop if both `row` and `col` are equal to `gridsize` - are you sure it is not going to negative? And that **both** are reaching **exactly** the gridsize? Also looks like if breaking out of second loop (`label == 0`), `option` is not changed and consequently neither `row` nor `col` changed -> infinite loop? But very hard to *forecast*, better use a debugger or, at least, print the positions being tested

Comment: please post [mre] and include hard-coded test data.